# Ошибка raise JSONDecodeError Python

Tags: python, json, api, post

При попытке сбора данных, появляется ошибка

`raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)`

Код:

```
aaa = [220417334, 219457998, 221285505]
for i in aaa:
    url = 'https://part.upnp.xyz/PartLive/GetResultGame'
    data = ({"GameId":[i],"lang":"ru"})
    res = requests.post(url, json=data)
    res1 = res.json()
    print(res1)
```

Причем по первому элементу в списке `aaa` данные получены, а далее ошибка. В чем может быть дело?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если сразу после совершения запроса посмотреть статус ответа (res.status_code), то видно, что на втором запросе сервер возвращает ошибку 503. Эта ошибка обозначает "Сервис временно недоступен".

Похоже, сервер не способен (или не хочет) обрабатывать несколько запросов сразу друг за другом. Если в конце каждой итерации цикла вы будете делать задержку (например, `time.sleep(1)`), то все три запроса нормально обрабатываются.

Comment: Большое спасибо!